# Firebase Update Email and Phone number. “this operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication.” Error on updateEmail ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a profile page in my app, where user can update phone number and email, so while updating email i am getting this error "this operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication"

Here is my code for update email

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.updateEmail(to: self.txtEmail.text ?? "", completion: { (err) in
                            
                        })
```

So i decided to use updatePhoneNumber method so it will show otp prompt and so phone number update is done in that method and we can consider it at recent login, so in completion block of updatePhoennumber method i am using updateemail method but still getting same error is there any other solution? we are not creating account with password so i don't have password for that email. So please let me know if i can do both operation in single verification. Below is my code

```
    let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
                withVerificationID: verificationId,
                verificationCode: verificationCode)
            if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
                
                user.updatePhoneNumber(credential) { (err) in
                    if let error = err {
                        
                        return
                    } else {

Auth.auth().currentUser?.updateEmail(to: self.txtEmail.text ?? "", completion: { (err) in
                                
                            })}
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You must re-authenticate the user using `reauthenticateWithCredential:completion:` on the `FIRUser` object. First, obtain the user's credentials (here are two examples):

```
let emailCredential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: "some@email.com", password: "somePassword")
let facebookCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: "someToken")
// or other
```

And then pass it into the reauthenticate method:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.reauthenticate(with: emailCredential, completion: { (result, error) in
    // go from here
})
```

Comment: but i am not using password while linking email to current account, so at updation time i will not have password

Comment: @GovindRakholiya you have to ask the user to re-enter it